# News sites in simple Korean

Tags: resources

could you recommend me some news sites that are written in simple Korean?
I tried to search a lot even sites for children but they are still too complex for me.
Each sentence in newspaper is ofen about 2-3 or even 4 lines.

I would like to find a website with simple Korean and also it can be copied or pasted too.
With this feature I can consult a dictionary quickly.
Also it would be great if there are some sites where there are English and Korean side by side.

Answer (score 1):

http://kids.donga.com/
http://kid.chosun.com/
http://www.koreakidnews.org/2006/home.php
http://www.econoi.co.kr/
here is some internet newspaper and sites written in easy Korean.
I founded it in 
https://www.moel.go.kr/kids/etc/familysite/list2.do
this is the list of recommended list of children newspaper and sites of the goverment.